# Convert time stamp to special date format

Tags: java

I'm using java to map timestamp into date with format `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`.

I'm using

```
Date meetingDate = new Date(Long.parseLong("1369662263618"));            
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(meetingDate.getTime()));
System.out.println(meetingDate);
```

The result is:

```
2013/05/27 15:44:23
2013-05-27
```

I want the date to be in that format like the first result.

Comment: Why in the first place are you printing `meetingDate`? You must understand that the `Date` as-is doesn't contain any specific format, instead is just a representation of the moment in time; you **must** use a `DateFormat` (`SimpleDateFormat` extends this class) to present your `Date` in the format you want/need.

Comment: The first result is simply Date.toString(), if you want your meetingDate printed like this, why not just print it as well? Or did I not understand your question?

Comment: @JoopEggen `java.util.Date` is not immutable =\.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza shame on me

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know what you want, but I think you want this:

```
 System.out.println(dateFormat.format(meetingDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the Date in any desired format you will have to use `DateFormat` .

As per [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html+) `SimpleDateFormat allows you to start by choosing any user-defined patterns for date-time formatting`

So you can use same `dateFormat` to get Text representation of your date

```
    Date meetingDate = new Date(Long.parseLong("1369662263618"));
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String meetingDateText=dateFormat.format(meetingDate);
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(meetingDate.getTime()));
    System.out.println(meetingDate);
    System.out.println(meetingDateText);
```